# About associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I have 3 Models. Proprietor, Property and Renter.
I'm confuse about Renter association because in my real estate system a tenant can have several leased properties.
Maybe has_many through ? If yes. How implement this?

```
class Proprietor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties, dependent: :destroy
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :proprietor
end

class Renter < ApplicationRecord
end

class CreateProprietors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :proprietors do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.date :birthday
      t.string :social_security
      t.string :doc_id
      t.text :address
      t.string :zip_code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.references :proprietor, foreign_key: true
      t.text :address
      t.string :zip_code
      t.integer :rooms
      t.integer :bedrooms
      t.integer :bathrooms
      t.integer :garage
      t.string :price
      t.boolean :published, defalt: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRenters < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :renters do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.date :birthday
      t.string :social_security
      t.string :doc_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a has_many through on this (unless properties can have many renters as well as renters having many properties?)

If the need is as you state in your question this should be achievable like so:

```
class Proprietor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties, dependent: :destroy
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :proprietor
  belongs_to :renter
end

class Renter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :properties
end

class CreateProprietors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :proprietors do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.date :birthday
      t.string :social_security
      t.string :doc_id
      t.text :address
      t.string :zip_code

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.references :proprietor, foreign_key: true
      t.references :renter, foreign_key: true
      t.text :address
      t.string :zip_code
      t.integer :rooms
      t.integer :bedrooms
      t.integer :bathrooms
      t.integer :garage
      t.string :price
      t.boolean :published, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateRenters < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :renters do |t|
      t.string :full_name
      t.string :email
      t.date :birthday
      t.string :social_security
      t.string :doc_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```